# How do I create a timedelta with pendulum?

Tags: pendulum

I'm looking for a way of creating an arbitrary `timedelta` compatible object with pendulum. Previously there was a `pendulum.interval` method but this seems to not exist in recent versions of pendulum.

So say I'd like a delta of five minutes: surely there's a way of doing this that's more elegant than creating two datetime objects and subtracting them? Ideally I'd like to say: `pendulum.timedelta(minutes=5)`.

Answer (score 5):

Just do:

`pendulum.duration(minutes=5)`